# RDD taken from spark DStream is not getting distributed between partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I have five executors running for this spark job, but RDD which comes from dstream only gets distributed between 2 partitions. If I do a `repartion(5)` then also it remains distributed among 2 partitions, but when I create a new RDD out of it by doing a `val newrdd= sparkcontext.parallelize(rdd.take(rdd.count()))`, then it gets distributed among the 5 partitions properly. But creating a new RDD after parallelizing an existing RDD is not a good idea, so I don't want to do this.

Am I missing something here?

Code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparksession.sparkContext, Seconds(batchDuration.toLong))
    val inputDirectStream = EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(
      ssc,
      eventHubNamespace,
      progressDir,
      Map(eventHubName -> eventhubParameters))


inputDirectStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
println(rdd.partitions.size)//it prints 2
rdd.repartition(5)
println(rdd.partitions.size)//it also prints 2
var newrdd = sparksession.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd.take(rdd.count().toInt))
println(newrdd.partitions.size)//it prints 5

}
```

I'm running my spark stream job as follows:

> spark-submit --class "com.mycomp.Main" --executor-memory 1g
>   --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 5 --conf "spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown=true" --master yarn --jars
>   /tmp/jobs/supporting.jar /tmp/jobs/cdc.jar false > /tmp/jobs/output
>   2>&1

Any suggestions on how to make the RDD get distributed between 5 partitions (depending upon number of executors and cores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `repartition` returns a new RDD (with changed partitioning) which you need to use. In other words, you need to assign the return value from the repartitioning call to a new variable, otherwise you are just working with the old RDD with the old partitioning. Change to `val rdd2 = rdd.repartition(5)` and work with `rdd2` after that.

**Note**: Since Scala is by design a lazy language, no actual repartitioning will take place until an action is performed on the data. For example, you could run `first` or `count` on the data to make it repartiton happen. However, checking the partitioning with `rdd.partitions.size` will still be correctly reflected.

Comment: Thanks @Shaido , this helped, but this way I created another copy of rdd in memory(one with 2 partition and another with 5 partition) I was wondering if something can be done in dstream so that rdd which comes from dstream itself will be distributed properly among partitions. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: @Mukesh_Mike: Since the first RDD is never used it will actually not be saved in memory. Spark will automatically optimize for things like this.

Comment: Thats real cool @Shaido :-)  Many thanks for your expert comment.

Comment: The first paragraph is irrelevant and confusing.  Partitioning is logical, so it is reflected, even if RDD is never evaluated.

Comment: @user8371915: Yes, you are correct. I have edited my answer somewhat to make it more clear.